# Getting a list of strings after a start string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, substring, reddit

I'm building a Reddit bot that 
Replies with a link to the app that the redditor specified

What I want to achieve is that the user comments with this text

> ilink: someapp, anotherapp

I have no problem getting the information and replying to the comment for a single argument

But not for multiple ones

Is it possible to get the line which contains the start string

> ilink:

then split all arguments after that word which are separated by a comma `,`
And put them into a result list

And thanks

Edit : 
Here is an example of multiple arguments with text that the bot should be able to find the arguments in

> i like this games so much check em out \n ilink: awsomeGame, cuteGame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the variable `foo` contains a string, then this should work:

```
if ("ilink:") in foo:
  arguments = foo[foo.find("ilink: ") + len("ilink: "):].split(",")
```

Hope that helps you with your bot!